# How use ajax-forms with polymer?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, polymer, ajax-forms

I'm trying to create a simple web app using polymer.

I have an email, name and checkbox field for the user.

What I would like to do is when the user enters their information into these inputs, the data is stored and sent to me.

I understand this may be a novice question, but I am finding difficulty to get this to work with the Polymer framework.

Below is my code. 
HTML

```
<paper-input-decorator id="decorator" label="{{label}}" floatinglabel="{{floatingLabel}}" value="{{value}}" disabled?="{{disabled}}">
    <input is="core-input" value="{{value}}" committedvalue="{{committedValue}}" on-change="{{changeAction}}" method="post" disabled?="{{disabled}}">
  </paper-input-decorator>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/ajax-form/ajax-form.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">

<form id="doSomethingForm" is="ajax-form" action="/api/doSomething" method="post">
    <paper-input label="Name" type="text" name="name"></paper-input>
    <paper-input label="Email" type="text" name="email"></paper-input>
    <paper-button id="submitButton" raised on-tap="{{submit}}">Submit</paper-button>
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
Polymer({
    submit: function() {
        this.$.doSomethingForm.submit();
    }
});
```

This will send a POST call to your server on endpoint `/api/doSomething` with parameters `name` and `email`

Comment: Great! Thanks for the response. 
This helps a lot. 
I have a few quick questions if you dont mind. 
1. under the 'action="doSomething"' what are some examples I can place in there? Where would this file be located? sorry if it's a dumb question. I just do not know how to set up the back-end or server endpoint.

Comment: Depends on your language of choice. If you are using Python you should try out [webapp2](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/) to set up your server endpoints.